# forloop.counter for two dimensional array in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

colleagues! In my template I'm iterating different lists, which contain different information (lists) for groups (teams).
I was trying to use forloop.counter. But it works only for one dimensional list. But I have a two-dimensional list:

```
team_members = [[''], ['','','',''], ['','','','']]
```

index filter:

```
@register.filter
def index(sequence, position):
    return sequence[position]
```

I have tryed this piece of code in past:

```
{% for team in teams %}
    {% for team_member in team_members %}
        {{ team_member|index:forloop.counter|index:forloop.counter }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I try this, all worked perfect.

```
{{team_members|index:1|index:0}}
```

But when I try this:

```
{{team_members|index:forloop.counter|index:0}}
```

where forloop.counter = 1
it wrotes me

> list index out of range

Can you please explain why?

When I write:

```
{{team_members|index:forloop.counter}}
```

it works perfect too.

**Edit**

```
<div class="card card-body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" twipsy-content-set="true" class="tooltip ficon-help-icon" title="Leader: 
                {% with team_member=team_members|index:forloop.counter %}
                    {{ team_member|index:0 }}
                {% endwith %}<br>Members: {{team_members.1.1}}">
                {{team.name|teamName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you even need `team_members|index:forloop.counter`? If you have a loop why aren't you getting the team member from the loop variable? Also `index` is not a builtin template filter, please see how to write a [mre].

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat, because I have a lot of teams which are in my loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chain the things like that the template engine will try to applu the `index` template filter on `forloop.counter` not on `team_members[forloop.counter]`.

The only way to control the order of evaluation is to use the [`{% with %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with team_member=team_members|index:forloop.counter %}
    {{ team_member|index:0 }}
    {# or with the dot syntax: #}
    {{ team_member.0 }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Bernhard Vallant, thanks! But I got indexError again. Can you check pls, I edited the topic.

Comment: Whats the excact erorr message now?

Comment: list index out of range {{ team_member|index:0 }}

Comment: So it"s probably not indexable? You would have to share your code where `team_members` comes from...

Comment: list team_members contains [[''], ['test1', 'test2'], []].
Maybe, it's because I'm using {% with %} in title...
upd. When I'm using {% with team_member=team_members|index:1 %}, it's ok, but  when using {% with team_member=team_members|index:forloop.counter %}, it wrotes me the same error.

Comment: Bernhard Vallant, understood, it happened because in the first team I have 2 members, but in the second only 1. Haha, thanks)

Comment: I have added an example of my list. So, the problem was that I lost some data from list of lists. But your example worked for me well. Thank you again. And I edited my question, maybe it will help someone else.